# AltBeacon getDistance() function vs beacon locate distance estimation

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

Hi everyone I'm using the alt beacon library to get the distance between my phone and various beacons.
I noticed that the results obtained by the App [Locate Beacon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&utm_source=downloadatoz.com) are way more precise than what I obtain from the library. Since I saw that the app and the library were developed by the same people I thought that the results would be comparable but this is definitely not the case.

Is there any way to see the app's source code or more generally to understand how to make my results as good as what the app gets?

**EDIT** after some testing with the reference app, that gives out the correct values, i noticed that in my app the runningAverage value is not correct (i monitored the RSSI of a beacon that are always between 45 and 55 while the average comes out as 64/65). I feel like i messed up the way the running average is computed by extending the class

This is my class

```
public class MyBeacon extends Beacon implements Serializable, Comparable {
public String btAddress;
public String area;
public double[] position;

private static Map<String, String> btToArea = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<String, double[]> positionsMap = new HashMap<>();

static {
    btToArea.put("DE:FD:0A:11:D8:80", "DEV OFFICE");
    btToArea.put("D1:75:7B:58:54:D6", "DEV OFFICE");
    btToArea.put("D6:81:6A:D5:09:40", "CENTRAL OFFICE");
    btToArea.put("F1:14:DC:C2:0C:08", "CENTRAL OFFICE");
    btToArea.put("FC:0D:4A:C1:CD:57", "DEV OFFICE");

    positionsMap.put("D6:81:6A:D5:09:40", new double[]{9.9, 3.9}); //
    positionsMap.put("FC:0D:4A:C1:CD:57", new double[]{0.0, 0.0}); //
    positionsMap.put("D1:75:7B:58:54:D6", new double[]{0.0, 2.5}); //
    positionsMap.put("F1:14:DC:C2:0C:08", new double[]{6.9, -1.0}); //
    positionsMap.put("DE:FD:0A:11:D8:80", new double[]{-0.4, 2.5});
}

public MyBeacon(Beacon beacon){
    super(beacon);
    this.btAddress = beacon.getBluetoothAddress();
    this.area = btToArea.getOrDefault(beacon.getBluetoothAddress(), "ERROR");
    this.position = positionsMap.get(beacon.getBluetoothAddress());
}

public static MyBeacon FromBeacon(Beacon beacon){
    if (positionsMap.containsKey(beacon.getBluetoothAddress()))
        return new MyBeacon(beacon);

    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    MyBeacon myBeacon = (MyBeacon) o;
    return Objects.equals(btAddress, myBeacon.btAddress) &&
            Objects.equals(area, myBeacon.area) &&
            Arrays.equals(position, myBeacon.position);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), btAddress, area);
    result = 31 * result + Arrays.hashCode(position);
    return result;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return (int) (((MyBeacon) o).getDistance() - this.getDistance());
}
```

}

Am i extending the class properly? Is my suspicious right or am i completely off?

Also the parser is custom if that might affect it

Comment: I would retest the case where you believe the running average RSSI is not consistent with the RSSI readings.  That is highly unlikely and I suspect the real problem is something else.  Try setting beaconManager.setDebug(true); and looking at zlogCat for each RSSI reading and the running average.

Comment: Hi, sorry to reopen this after quite a while but i got to work on the devices again and noticed that a couple of them are set to have the same id, and their running average (and consequentially distance) "converges" so i was wondering if maybe the running average is tied to the ID1 rather than the BT address as i initially tought. This still confues me tho because the Locate app looks like it's unaffected by it and the two beacons show way different distances. As soon as my colleague changes the IDs i'll run further tests but i thought i'd ask in advance just in case it is pointless

Comment: You can track beacons with the same identifier as being distinct by MAC address with [this setting](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/Beacon.html#setHardwareEqualityEnforced-boolean-)

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the Locate Beacon app does indeed just use the `Beacon#getDistance()` method, so it's unclear why you are seeing differences.  The latest version in the Play Store uses a slightly older version of the library `org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.2`, but not much has changed there.

I wrote Locate Beacon, so I can assure you there is nothing secret going on with the distance estimates relative to what you get in the open source library -- it just has a fancier UI.  You might try testing with the library's reference app, to see what kind of distance estimates it gives you.  This might eliminate any subtle coding issues in your own app.

Comment: Hi, that's what i feared, i'll do as you suggested thanks!

Comment: I edited my question with my findings, i'm still really confused about what is going on